# Changed the domain name of heroku ruby on rails app, user mailer emails sending links to wrong domain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm building a Ruby on Rails app, and I'm hosting it on heroku. I built the application up for a little bit, where users can sign up and they get an email where they have to verify their account. After implementing those features, I changed the name of my heroku app using heroku rename command. I also changed the .git, and on the heroku side of things everything transitioned fine. But I have a User Mailer component that sends emails to activate account, the activation links are still linking to the old domain name. How do I update the user mailer to send links to new domain name?

This is the line that is generating the faulty urls I think. This is in the html.erb of the actual email itself that the user receives.

```
<%= link_to "Activate", edit_account_activation_url(@user.activation_token,
                                             email: @user.email) %>
```

Comment: Not sure whether this might be relevant, but have you restarted the server?

Comment: Phew! Thanks, that fixed it. I didn't realize I would have had to reset the heroku server, I did so using the heroku restart -a app_name command and it fixed my issue.